# How to display many to many field as searchable choice

Tags: django, django-forms

In my django app I have a many to many connection with a lot of choices. In the admin panel I could solve this problem very elegantly through 
[django-salmonella](https://github.com/lincolnloop/django-salmonella)

But now I would like to have the possibility to have a searchable choice in a user accessible form. 
[image: many to many selection]

How can I do that? Is there a good package that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the [django-autocomplete-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light) package in several of my projects. It is based on the javascript library [select2](https://select2.org).
It is very useful both to ChoiceField and MultiChoiceField. You must enable a view to perform the search by AJAX.